# How do I change the text "Thanks for spending some quality time with the Web site today." in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin

When you log out of the Django admin, it displays a string "Thanks for spending some quality time with the Web site today."

Can I change that to something else?

I was able to change other attributes such as

```
admin.site.site_header = "Whatever"
admin.site.site_title = "Whatever"
admin.site.index_title = "Whatever"
```

in the urls.py file which worked great so I am guessing this can be changed similarly.

Thanks for your help.  Tried Google, no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the text by using the following steps:

Step 1: In your `settings.py` file in the `TEMPLATES` section, give path of your templates directory created by you for overridding the `logged_out.html` template file.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],  // path of your templates folder
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Step 2: Create a directory `registration` in your templates folder.

Step 3: Now create `logged_out.html` file in registration folder.

Step 4: Change the content according to you requirement

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block breadcrumbs %}<div class="breadcrumbs"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% translate 'Home' %}</a></div>{% endblock %}

{% block nav-sidebar %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<p>{% translate "Thanks for spending some quality time with the Web site today." %}</p>

<p><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% translate 'Log in again' %}</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Amazing.  Thank you.  Am I assuming correctly that you can add other html files into that registration folder that will alter the display of other pages also?

Comment: And if so... is there some source that can show me those different files and the basic layout similar to what you gave me for that logged_out page?

Comment: Yes, you can get other files on github also. - https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your help very much.